# Add date range to NgbInputDatepicker input field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, ng-bootstrap

I am working with **Angular 5.2 and ngbootstrap 1.1**.  The library has a couple of different datepicker options one that serves as a component and another that serves as a directive.

I am working with the directive.  Below is a link to an example of how to setup ngbootstrap's directive with a template.

[directive example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skbpc8?file=app%2Fdatepicker-popup.html)

When two dates are selected the popover adds one date inside of the input.

In my initial approach I attempted to set

```
[(ngModel)]=model
```

and

```
 this.model = `${this.fromDate} / ${this.toDate}`;
```

However, I realized that after setting model.  The date was checked inside of another component provided by **ngbootstrap's datepicker module**.

```
private _fromDateStruct(date: NgbDateStruct): NgbDate {
  const ngbDate = date ? new NgbDate(date.year, date.month, date.day) : null;
  return this._calendar.isValid(ngbDate) ? ngbDate : null;
}
```

[link to component code](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker-input.ts)

Also the private method above makes it impossible to extend the class and override the check

```
class DateInputDirective extends NgbInputDatepicker
```

I dug a little deeper and hoped that I could change a service.  **NgbDateAdapter** service returns the object or null if it is not accurate.  My string date range could not get past this.

[NgBootstrap API](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api)

```
fromModel(date: NgbDateStruct): NgbDateStruct {
  return (date && date.year && date.month && date.day) ? {year: date.year, month: date.month, day: date.day} : null;
```

}

Also, I took advantage of angular's **useClass** and slipped a string conditional.

```
{
    provide: NgbDateAdapter,
    useClass: NgbStringAdapter
},
```

However, the NgbDatePickerInput class overrode the behavior before this class finalized.

Not sure if I am missing something very simple Or if it is a matter of using extends or useClass a few more times.  But I am definitely looking for some insight on this.  The stackblitz link is not my actual code but is a good representation of what I started with.  Feel free to reach out if something was not written clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `ElementRef` and `ViewChild` to set the input value would work.

I mean not using `ViewChild` with the Directive/Component( `NgbInputDatepicker` ), because all accessor to the element from the directive are private and I dont see how to change the input from there unless in  `_writeModelValue` method [(line 363)](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker-input.ts) , `writeValue` call it, but it only update one date.

So the steps are:

- by using `ElementRef` and `ViewChild` to having the input element,
- and `Renderer2` for setting its value (like the directive do)
- and using `NgbDateParserFormatter` to format the model date
- You just need to do this when date is selected, so in the method `onDateSelection`

This is the main code, I'll add some comments:

HTML:

```
<input
     #myRangeInput
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
    name="dp" 
    [(ngModel)]="model" 
    ngbDatepicker 
    [dayTemplate]="t"
    [autoClose]="false"
    [displayMonths]="2"
    [maxDate]="maxDate"
    [minDate]="minDate"
>
    <ng-template #t let-date="date" let-focused="focused">
        <span class="custom-day"
            [class.range]="isFrom(date) || isTo(date) || isInside(date) || isHovered(date)"
            [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
            (click)="onDateSelection(date)"
            (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
            (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null"
            >
        {{ date.day }}
        </span>
    </ng-template>
```

TYPESCRIPT:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import {
    NgbDatepicker, 
    NgbInputDatepicker, 
    NgbDateStruct, 
    NgbCalendar, 
    NgbDateAdapter,
    NgbDateParserFormatter} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
export class NgbdDatepickerPopup implements OnInit{
  ...
 @ViewChild('myRangeInput') myRangeInput: ElementRef;
 constructor(element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, private _parserFormatter: NgbDateParserFormatter) { }
 onDateSelection(date: NgbDateStruct) {
        let parsed = ''; // initializing with empty string
        if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
            this.fromDate = date;
        } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && after(date, this.fromDate)) {
            this.toDate = date;
            this.input.close();
        } else {
            this.toDate = null;
            this.fromDate = date;
        }
        if(this.fromDate) {
          // if fromDate is set: add the first date
          parsed += this._parserFormatter.format(this.fromDate);
        }
        if(this.toDate) {
          // if toDate is set: add the second date with separator
          parsed += ' - ' + this._parserFormatter.format(this.toDate);
        }
        // here we update the input value with the new parsed value
        this.renderer.setProperty(this.myRangeInput.nativeElement, 'value', parsed);
    }
```

And this is the working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skbpc8-maun8a

Comment: Thanks!  This was just an example that I set up.  I had viewChild in my current code base but did not use Renderer2 as you did.  Killing myself for missing that.  I spent nearly a week trying to change the value on native element.

Comment: Great work!!. Is it possible to enter dates in input range itself and update dates in both date pickers for more good user experience? same like we have in daterangepicker.com JS

Comment: @AakashKumar I have created a component for that https://github.com/fetrarij/ngx-daterangepicker-material/

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct and I would had made this a comment had I the required reputation but since I cant, here is a snippet of css you can add to styles.css to complete the functionality.

```css
.ngb-dp-day.disabled[_ngcontent-c21], .ngb-dp-day.hidden[_ngcontent-c21] {
  cursor: default;
  color: #d0d0d0;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;   /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;  /* IE 10+ */
   user-select: none;  /* Likely future */
}
```

This will make the disabled by min/maxDate or by markDisabled dates to look faded and unselectable.